# Pandas Dataframe merging columns

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like the following

```
Year  Month  Day Securtiy Trade  Value  NewDate
2011      1   10     AAPL   Buy   1500        0
```

My question is, how can I merge the columns `Year`, `Month`, `Day` into column `NewDate`
so that the `newDate` column looks like the following

```
2011-1-10
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to parse it when reading as csv:

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', sep='\s+', parse_dates=[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
       Year_Month_Day Securtiy Trade  Value  NewDate
0 2011-01-10 00:00:00     AAPL   Buy   1500        0
```

*You can do this without the header, by defining column names while reading:*

```
pd.read_csv(input_file, header=['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Security','Trade', 'Value' ], parse_dates=[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
```

If it's already in your DataFrame, you could use an apply:

```
In [11]: df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda s: pd.Timestamp('%s-%s-%s' % (s['Year'], s['Month'], s['Day'])), 1)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   Year  Month  Day Securtiy Trade  Value  NewDate                Date
0  2011      1   10     AAPL   Buy   1500        0 2011-01-10 00:00:00
```

Comment: Unfortunately , my input csv files does not have headers. I had to do this add headers.df.columns = ['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Security','Trade','Value' ]. So , i have to reformat the dataframe to achieve the concatenation of YYYY-MM-DD into Newdate column

Comment: @trinity you can also do it from the position so [[0, 1, 2]], or reference by name when using the header argument of read_csv

Comment: You mean , df = pd.read_csv(input_file , header = None, parse_dates=[[0,1,2]]) ??

Comment: or pd.read_csv(input_file, header=['Year', 'Month', ...], parse_dates=[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])

Comment: I tried that , and seems i am violating some syntax. The following error thrown.TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: You do not need to use double square brackets for the `parse_dates` parameter for `read_csv`, just a simple list will do using single square brackets, just in case you weren't aware of this.

Comment: @EdChum hmm, I was under the impression a list, parsed each of the columns individually as dates (i.e. would try to give you three date columns).

Comment: @AndyHayden Sorry, you are correct a list of lists parses the enclosed list as a composite of columns for a single date column, I didn't read the column names so I thought you were trying to parse 3 separate date columns.

Answer (score 1):

df['Year'] + '-' + df['Month'] + '-' + df['Date']

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Timestamp as follows:

```
df['newDate'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp('{0}-{1}-{2}'
                                                .format(x.Year, x.Month, x.Day),
                                   axix=1)

>>> df
   Year  Month  Day Securtiy Trade  Value  NewDate    newDate
0  2011      1   10     AAPL   Buy   1500        0 2011-01-10
```